# Populate/Fill listbox in a pdf template programmatically with a list in c# code

Tags: c#, itext

So I have  a listbox in my pdf template that I have named it "qte", and some other textfields, I use Itextsharp to populate the fields, populating textfields works fine but listboxes are not

here is some code :

```
stamper.AcroFields.SetField("Client", label2.Text);
stamper.AcroFields.SetField("Qte", label2.Text);
stamper.AcroFields.SetField("Qte", label2.Text);
stamper.AcroFields.SetField("Qte", label2.Text);
stamper.AcroFields.SetField("Qte", label2.Text);
stamper.AcroFields.SetField("Qte", label2.Text);
```

What I've come to understand is that lists are not populated the same as textfields , maybe not with stamper.
Can someone give me the solution?
thank you!

Comment: The question is unclear. A "Choice" field (e.g. represented by a list box) contains a series of keys and values. When you fill out a text field, you can choose which text to add as value, but if you want to fill out a choice fields, you have to pick one of the available keys. Do you know which keys are available? Are you using one of those keys (if not, nothing will happen). Or did I misinterpret your question. Are you asking how to replace the existing keys and values with new keys and values? Please clarify.

Comment: stamper.AcroFields.SetField("Client", label2.Text); works fine because "client" is a textfield, but  "qte" is a listbox, my problem is that "qte" is not populated

Comment: @SaifeddineAbid, try using `stamper.AcroFields.SetField("qte", new[] { label2.Text} );` A list could also need a list as a datasource.

Comment: The solution is to create programmatically new textfields for each element in my list! Thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, I now understand that you are confusing the concept of "filling out a choice field" with the concept of "setting list options".

Suppose that you have a list field named `language` with the following options:

- Option: "English"; value: "en"
- Option: "French"; value: "fr"
- Option: "Dutch"; value: "nl"

In that case, you would fill out the field like this:

```
stamper.AcroFields.SetField("language", "nl");
```

The following line wouldn't do anything:

```
stamper.AcroFields.SetField("language", "de");
```

It wouldn't do anything because the value `"de"` is not valid for the `language` Choice field.

It appears to me that you don't necessarily want to fill out a Choice field, but that you want to populate a list with new values.

For instance:

```
string[] languages = new string[] { "English", "French", "Dutch", "German" };
string[] exportvalues = new string[] { "en", "fr", "nl", "de" };
stamper.AcroFields.SetListOption("language", languages, exportvalues);
```

Now the field `language` will have four options instead of three:

- Option: "English"; value: "en"
- Option: "French"; value: "fr"
- Option: "Dutch"; value: "nl"
- Option: "German"; value: "de"

This will result in which the following line will select the correct option:

```
stamper.AcroFields.SetField("language", "de");
```

Now that I've finished my answer, I see that this question was already answered before: [Adding listchoices to Pdfform with c# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37405676/adding-listchoices-to-pdfform-with-c-sharp-code)

Comment: I've tried your solution it works, but , I don't want to populate a choice field, it's a simple list wich I want to fill it with values from a c# list or array.                         Thank you

Comment: A "simple list" is a common type of a "choice field". That's why the method is called `setListOptions()`. You have just made your question unanswerable. What is, according to you, the difference between a list and a choice field???